# Redis Message Queue (Cloud)

Tags: c#, redis

I am in the process of writing a Cloud application (mostly hobby, learning) that required a very quick cache, queue, and messaging system. I have looked at a few different options from Microsoft (hosting is on Azure) and all seem to be slow (for my relative needs). Then I hit Redis, and the speed was right where I needed it to be for what I am using.

Other thoughts that I had before using this, is that I also want to keep my usage of components down to a minimum, in case I need to move from Azure to baremetal, etc, I can always host my own Redis.

I decided, for both learning and for sport, to write a queue system that could work as a `AtMostOnce` or `AtLeastOnce` that would be reliable over system failure. This class should also be able to be run on multiple machines (in this case `workerroles`) and be instanced by either IoC or manually.

The following is what I have so far, before I take care of some of the problems I have not implemented yet (`cancellationTokens`, shared `ConnectionMultiplexer` for instance). The following code does work as I have tested it on 3 different `WorkerRoles` instances, while also testing crashes and reboots. My concerns are aimed more at problems that I don't see, performance issues, and my lack of general experience. Feel free to tell me if I'm doing anything wrong, but be aware that I am aware there are packages out there already. I just like to do things myself.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace CitySurvival.WorkerCommon
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Needed: (2) Redis queues 1 for new messages, 1 for currently processing messages
    /// Needed: processing messages list is FILO
    /// 
    /// The queues will only contain the key to the message in redis, which is stored as
    /// a single entity for quick lookup
    /// 
    /// jobQueue  -- processingQueue
    /// job:1        job:2
    /// 
    /// job:1 (job to do index 1)
    /// job:2 (job to do index 2)
    /// 
    /// Finish method, will LREM key, and Remove Key from database
    /// 
    /// ON adding a new job, send a Publish to say a new job is added
    /// 
    /// ON taking a job, RPOPLPUSH from jobQueue to processingQueue
    /// 
    /// Checking for failed jobs, experation time 10 seconds (this should be long enough 
    /// to process anything)
    /// If job stays in processingQueue for longer than timeout, RPOPLPUSH to jobQueue
    /// 
    /// TODO: cancellationTokens (being in with autofac for global token or use Factory param)
    /// TODO: Get ConnectionMultiplexer from Constructor, or Factory
    /// </summary>
    public class RedisJobQueue
    {
        public delegate RedisJobQueue Factory(string jobName);
        private IConnectionMultiplexer ConnectionMultiplexer => _lazyConnection.Value;

        private readonly Lazy<IConnectionMultiplexer> _lazyConnection = new Lazy<IConnectionMultiplexer>(() => StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("ConnctionString"));

        private readonly string _jobQueue;
        private readonly string _processingQueue;
        private readonly string _subChannel;
        private readonly string _jobName;

        private Task _managementTask;

        private bool _receiving;

        public event EventHandler<JobReceivedEventArgs> OnJobReceived; 

        public RedisJobQueue(/*ConnectionMultiplexer multiplexer, */string jobName)
        {
            //_connectionMultiplexer = multiplexer;
            _jobQueue = jobName + ":jobs";
            _processingQueue = jobName + ":process";
            _subChannel = jobName + ":channel";
            _jobName = jobName;
        }



        private IDatabase Database => ConnectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();

        /// <summary>
        /// When a job is finished, remove it from the processingQueue and from the
        /// cache database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <param name="failed">Operation failed, requeue for another attempt</param>
        public async Task Finish(string key, bool failed = false)
        {
            var db = Database;
            await db.ListRemoveAsync(_processingQueue, key);

            if (failed)
            {
                // How many times to fail before dead
                if (await db.HashExistsAsync(key, "failedcount"))
                {
                    var count = await db.HashGetAsync(key, "failedcount");
                    if (count.IsInteger)
                    {
                        if ((int) count >= 10)
                        {
                            // for now, delete the key, later we might integrate a dead message
                            // queue
                            await db.KeyDeleteAsync(key);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

                db.HashIncrement(key, "failedcount");
                db.HashDelete(key, "active");
                db.ListRightPush(_jobQueue, key);

                ConnectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber().Publish(_subChannel, "");
            }
            else
            {
                // Job was successfully run, remove the key
                await db.KeyDeleteAsync(key);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Do we consume messages from the queue
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public RedisJobQueue AsConsumer()
        {
            var sub = ConnectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber();
            sub.Subscribe(_subChannel, (channel, value) => HandleNewJobs());

            // Assume on starting that we have jobs waiting to be handled
            HandleNewJobs();
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Runs a Task every 10 seconds to see if any remaining items are in
        /// processing queue
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public RedisJobQueue AsManager()
        {
            _managementTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(10000);
                    var timeToKill = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds - 10000;
                    RedisValue[] values = Database.ListRange(_processingQueue);
                    foreach (var value in from value in values let activeTime = (double)Database.HashGet((string)value, "active") where activeTime < timeToKill select value)
                    {
                        await Finish(value, true);
                    }
                }
            });

            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Move key from JobQueue to processingQueue, get key value from cache.
        /// 
        /// Also set the active field. Indicates when job was retrieved so we can monitor
        /// its time.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Dictionary<RedisValue, RedisValue> GetJob()
        {
            Dictionary<RedisValue, RedisValue> value;
            while (true)
            {
                string key = Database.ListRightPopLeftPush(_jobQueue, _processingQueue);
                // If key is null, then nothing was there to get, so no value is available
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                {
                    value = new Dictionary<RedisValue, RedisValue>();
                    break;
                }

                Database.HashSet(key, "active", (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds);
                value = Database.HashGetAll(key).ToDictionary();

                if (value.Count == 0)
                {
                    Database.ListRemove(_processingQueue, key);
                    continue;
                }
                value.Add("key", key);
                break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Move key from JobQueue to processingQueue, get key value from cache.
        /// 
        /// Also set the active field. Indicates when job was retrieved so we can monitor
        /// its time.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task<Dictionary<RedisValue, RedisValue>> GetJobAsync()
        {
            var db = Database;
            Dictionary<RedisValue, RedisValue> value;
            while (true)
            {
                string key = await db.ListRightPopLeftPushAsync(_jobQueue, _processingQueue);
                // If key is null, then nothing was there to get, so no value is available
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                {
                    value = new Dictionary<RedisValue, RedisValue>();
                    break;
                }

                await db.HashSetAsync(key, "active", (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds);
                value = (await db.HashGetAllAsync(key)).ToDictionary();

                // if Count is 0, remove it and check for the next job
                if (value.Count == 0)
                {
                    await db.ListRemoveAsync(_processingQueue, key);
                    continue;
                }

                value.Add("key", key);

                break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// We have received an indicator that new jobs are available
        /// We process until we are out of jobs.
        /// </summary>
        private async void HandleNewJobs()
        {
            if (_receiving)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Already Receiving Jobs...");
                return;
            }
            _receiving = true;
            Trace.WriteLine("Trying to get jobs...");
            var job = await GetJobAsync();
            // If a valid job cannot be found, it will return an empty Dictionary
            while (job.Count != 0)
            {
                // Fire the Event
                OnJobReceived?.Invoke(this, new JobReceivedEventArgs(job, job["key"]));
                // Get a new job if there is one
                job = await GetJobAsync();
            }
            _receiving = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add a job to the Queue
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="job"></param>
        public void AddJob(RedisValue job)
        {
            if (job.IsNullOrEmpty) return;

            var id = Database.StringIncrement(_jobName + ":jobid");
            var key = _jobName + ":" + id;
            Database.HashSet(key, "payload", job);
            Database.ListLeftPush(_jobQueue, key);
            ConnectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber().Publish(_subChannel, "");
            Trace.WriteLine("Added Job");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add a job to the Queue (async)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="job"></param>
        public async Task AddJobAsync(RedisValue job)
        {
            if (job.IsNullOrEmpty) return;

            var id = await Database.StringIncrementAsync(_jobName + ":jobid");
            var key = _jobName + ":" + id;
            await Database.HashSetAsync(key, "payload", job);
            await Database.ListLeftPushAsync(_jobQueue, key);
            await ConnectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber().PublishAsync(_subChannel, "");
            Trace.WriteLine("Added Job");
        }
    }
}
```

### New Code

I have added and edited a few items from the original code, have also incorperated some changes listed below. The new code can be found on Github in this gist [GitHub Gist for Redis Job/Message Queue](https://gist.github.com/tenowg/c5de38cb1027ab875e56)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- dead code like in the constructor arguments for `RedisJobQueue` should be deleted. To keep track of changes a version control system like GIT or SVN should be used.
- You are using C# 6.0 so you can make use of the string interpolation using the `$` operator like so

  ```
  public RedisJobQueue(string jobName)
  {
      _jobQueue =  $"{jobName}:jobs";
      _processingQueue = $"{jobName}:process";
      _subChannel = $"{jobName}:channel";
      _jobName = jobName;
  }
  ```
- if possible reduce horizontal spacing by using guard conditions. For the `Finish()` method this can be done easily by inverting the condition of the `if` and returning early like so

  ```
  public async Task Finish(string key, bool failed = false)
  {
      var db = Database;
      await db.ListRemoveAsync(_processingQueue, key);

      if (!failed)
      {
          await db.KeyDeleteAsync(key);
          return;
      }

      // How many times to fail before dead
      if (await db.HashExistsAsync(key, "failedcount"))
      {
          var count = await db.HashGetAsync(key, "failedcount");
          if (count.IsInteger)
          {
              if ((int) count >= 10)
              {
                  // for now, delete the key, later we might integrate a dead message
                  // queue
                  await db.KeyDeleteAsync(key);
                  return;
              }
          }
      }

      db.HashIncrement(key, "failedcount");
      db.HashDelete(key, "active");
      db.ListRightPush(_jobQueue, key);

      ConnectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber().Publish(_subChannel, "");
  }
  ```

  you could consider to change the parameter `failed` to `success` with a default value of `true` to prevent the negative check `!failed`, but this will involve some major changes to the caller of this method.
- you can remove the duplicated code where you have both , synchronously and asynchronously methods, like so

  ```
  private Dictionary<RedisValue, RedisValue> GetJob()
  {
      return Task.Run(GetJobAsync).Result;
  }
  ```

  See also: [calling-async-method-synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22629216/2655508)

Comment: I will be working on this some more later to night, but one suggestion that doesn't seem to make sense. I had thought that the 'Task.Run(GetJobAsync).Result' would work originally myself. I have seen that pattern enough :), but done this simply for me returns `Ambigious invocation` errors. So I have to use Run(() => GetJobAsync()) instead, not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

In `AsManager` you start a long running task - you should pass the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` to `StartNew` to help the framework making better decisions.

Also the task runs in a `while (true)` loop without an obvious bailout condition. It would probably a bit cleaner if you pass a `CancellationToken` to it so you can cancel the task and end it when shutting down

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have already changed all the while(true)s to use cancellationTokens (check out the gist I linked at the bottom), I wish CR would allow the use of gists in questions. I didn't think about the TaskCreationOptions, i will look into that.